# random vertices up-Z/down-Z only..?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I try to ask you..

I did tried randomize resulted: right-X/left-X/up-Y/down-Y

but it's not work up-Z/down-Z..

I want to use random up-Z/down-Z..... only

how do I will do? it's missing?

sorry for my poor English..

thank you

Comment: what are you trying to randomize ? Vertices? Objects ? Are you using Randomize Transform?

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: I assume you want to randomize the vertex positions of a mesh object.

### Displace modifier

One solution, that will work on any mesh is to use the 'Displace' modifier.

1. Add a 'Displace' modifier to the mesh object you want to add noise to. Set 'Direction' to 'Z' and add a texture (use the big new button).

[image: Displace modifier image]

2. Open the texture tab, and change the type of the texture to 'Noise' (if you want uniform noise, use clouds with small scale instead).

[image: Texture settings image]

3. Play around with the 'Strength' property of the modifier, until you get the needed result (Circled in the first image).

### Randomize tool

Alternatively, you can use the 'Randomize' Mesh editing tool if all your normals are on ±Z (e.g. a grid). To do this, make sure that you set the 'normal' option to 1.0 (boxed on the image below).

[image: Randomize tool and options]

Comment: Phew! That was a bit long....

Comment: thank you for your TIPS and TRICK! but i have lattice, lattice has not Idisplace... :-(   that is good trick really!! i will use it in mesh but not lattice..

Comment: @Manuelsongokuh you should have said in the main question that you want to randomize the vertexes of a lattice.... If you edit it, I think it will no longer be "unclear".